# how to level a data in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, file, data-annotations

I have an excel files which contains file names like:["oil_1%_water_2%"],["oil_2%_water_4%"],["oil_6%_water_1%"]..... And it's a column matrix data. Now I have to annotate the data. For example if water percentage is higher than oil then level it as 1. And if Oil percentage is higher then level the data as -1. Can anyone please tell me how to do that using python.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a time series dataset of a mixture which contain oil and water. Each of the dataset named as oil_x%_water_y%. Now I have to make a separate excel file which will only contains these dataset names and there level. Suppose my dataset name is oil_1%_water2%. Here my water percentage is greater than 1%. So my sample is good and I want to level this sample as 1. Now  in that separate excel file the entry would be like, oil_1%_water2%,1.